# Testing chained Promises with AngularJS $http in karma

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, promise, httpbackend

I'm trying to return a Promise in a Promise after a $http call, but it never gets resolved in the karma/jasmine test case.

Here's the code:

```
$httpBackend.expectGET('/dummy').respond('foo');
var p = $http.get('/dummy').then(function(response) {return response.data;});
//var p = Promise.resolve('foo');  // if you use this, it works
p = p.then(function(x) {
    expect(x).toEqual('foo');
    return Promise.resolve(x+'bar');  // return follow-up promise
}).then(function(x) {
    expect(x).toEqual('foobar');
    console.log('Hooray!');
});
$httpBackend.flush();
```

Of course, the test case passes, but the second Promise is never resolved. If I use `waitsFor` to check that `p` is settled, karma shows a timeout error.

As it would work with a simple `Promise.resolve('foo')` (see above), the problem seems to be that `$httpBackend.flush()` only flushes the first promise, but not the returned second promise.

Random `$rootScope.$apply()` didn't resolve the problem either. I also tried initializing `beforeEach(module('myModule'))` but since the module isn't used I don't see the point anyway. What am I missing?

Comment: does that suggest that `response.data` is not "foo" to you?

Comment: No, the $http response works perfectly fine. The then() with the expect(x).toEqual('foo') is executed, the next then() however is not.

Comment: but it works if you uncomment the commented line?

Comment: Yes, when I use a simple Promise created by Promise.resolve instead of $http.get, it works.
As we're just testing Promises and there is no actual module needed, you can easily reproduce this...